# Trying to setup jqGrid in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

In the past I've been using (free-)jqGrid (version 4.14 in ASP application with success. Now I'm setting up an Angular application and try to integrate the grid in a component. The grid is not showing up and in console I don't get any errors. Can anyone help me with this or are there any alternatives?

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<table id="tblOffers" class="scroll" ></table>
<div id="pager" class="scroll"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//(function ($){
    var $offers = jQuery("#tblOffers");

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $offers.jqGrid({
            url: '/data/data.json',
            datatype: "json",
            colNames: [ 'Offernumber' ],
            colModel: [ { name: 'OfferNr', index: 'OfferNr' } ],
            height: 200,
            width: 720
        });
    });
//})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Try using: 
http://ui-grid.info/
I'm using that one and I would recommend it, it's really good with great documentation. There's one both for AnularJS and Angular.

Comment: have you imported jquery in your app

Comment: @RahulSingh Yes in my index.html I added a script line for jquery.min.js

Comment: are you using cli ?

Comment: @RahulSingh No that package is not included.